# Append incremental number to existing functions

Tags: python, python-2.7

I started the python 2.7 script below with a single list named "REG_LOADS" but now I would like to change the name to REG_LOADS_40 and add additional list such as "REG_LOADS_41", and several more. How can I modify the functions that already exist to append the "_40" or "_041" or "_xx" to the functions? My end goal is to have several list named 40, 41, 42, 43, etc.. and have the program increment the lists.

Thanks,

```
def bytes(word):
global data_high
global data_low
data_high, data_low = divmod(word, 0x100)


def read_reg_22(): #must read register 22 (0x16) before chaging the page
   print(hex(REG_LOADS[x][0]), hex(0x16), hex(2))

def set_page_4(): #set phy page to 4 for writing to non-volatile memory
    print (hex(REG_LOADS[x][0]), hex(0x16), hex(0x0004), hex(2))

def write_to_nvm(): #write to 88E1112 non-volatile memory register
    print (hex(REG_LOADS[x][0]), hex(0x12), hex(0xA000+(REG_LOADS[x][data_ctr])), hex(0x02))

def write_to_nvm_high(): #write to 88E1112 non-volatile memory register
    print (hex(REG_LOADS[x][0]), hex(0x12), hex(0xA000+(data_high)), hex(0x02))

def write_to_nvm_low(): #write to 88E1112 non-volatile memory register
    print (hex(REG_LOADS[x][0]), hex(0x12), hex(0xA000+(data_low)), hex(0x02))

def send_nvm_to_eeprom(): #write to 88E1112 to send data in nvm to EEPROM
    print (hex(REG_LOADS[x][0]), hex(0x10), hex(0xA000+(eeprom_ctr)), hex(0x02))

# PHY_ADDR, PHY_PAGE, PHY_REG, REG_DATA
REG_LOADS = [[0x40, 0x00, 0x01, 0x1234],[0x41, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFFFF],[0x42, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAAAA], [0x40, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAAAA]]


print ("Checking that all PHYs are available")
if (1):
    PHY_Success = 1
    print ("Success, PHYs [64, 65, 67, 71, 72, 75, 76, 79, 80] were found")
else:
    PHY_Success = 0
    print ("Failure, all PHYs were not found")

if PHY_Success == 1:
    data_ctr = 1
    eeprom_ctr = 0x00
    x = 0
    for a in range(len(REG_LOADS)):
        read_reg_22()
        set_page_4()
        for i in range(len(REG_LOADS[0])+1):
            if data_ctr <= 2:
                write_to_nvm()
                send_nvm_to_eeprom()
            if data_ctr == 3:
                bytes (REG_LOADS[x][data_ctr])
                write_to_nvm_high()
                send_nvm_to_eeprom()
            if data_ctr == 4:
                write_to_nvm_low()
                send_nvm_to_eeprom()
            data_ctr +=1
            eeprom_ctr +=1
        data_ctr = 1
        eeprom_ctr =0x00
        x += 1

else:
    print ("Fail")
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a number of individually named lists and a function corresponding to each list, I'd recommend a dictionary of lists and a function that takes that list's key like so:

```
# Assuming the numbers refer to PHYs:
phys = {
    40: [],
    41: [],
    ...
}

def increment_phy(phy_key):
    phys[phy_key] = whatever you want to do with it
```